# converting an integer into an iterable object to facilitate code reuse

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, overloading, iterable

I am creating a datatype that needs to support two methods:

```
length(int v, int w) 
length(Iterable<Integer> v, Iterable<Integer> w)
```

the first one is a special case of the second method and I want to reuse the code. How do I efficiently convert an integer into an Iterable object?

So far, I used an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); a.add(v);
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(); b.add(w);
return length(a,b);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What will the 2 methods do?

Comment: In this particular case, it returns the length of shortest path between two nodes or two sets of nodes. But the question was meant to be for a general case.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution ?

Comment: You can turn a single object into an iterable of just that object with the `Collections.singleton()` library method. So your 3 line solution becomes a single line `length(Collections.singleton(v), Collections.singleton(w));`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the same method? I think it is better use two differents methods, this is the purpose of overloading.
When you use the `Iterable` you have to use autoboxing of java to create `Integer` and then create the `ArrayList`, it is worse than use two differents methods, also to let the code more simple to read.
But if you want to use only Iterable I would use this code (to use the less possible code) or @sisyphus code:

```
length(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(2));
```

Merging `varargs` with `ArrayList` conversion allows you to create an `ArrayList` in a cool way.

Here you can see the working code:
[code Iterable](http://goo.gl/Gzqyq8)